# Exception Handling Python TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable

Tags: python-3.x, exception

I am **scraping** a list of urls with the same html format. Here is my **scraper**

```
import requests, bs4, csv, json
from pprint import pprint

with open('playerslist.json') as data_file:
    data = json.load(data_file)
    for i in data['player']:
        name = i['player_name']
        url = 'https://www.capfriendly.com/players/'+name
        r = requests.get(url)
        soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')
        table = soup.find(id="cont_x")

        with open(name+".csv", "w", newline='') as team_data:
            def parse_td(td):
                filtered_data = [tag.text for tag in td.find_all('span', recursive=False)
                                    if 'q' not in tag.attrs['class']]
                return filtered_data[0] if filtered_data else td.text;

            for tr in table('tr', class_=['column_head', 'odd', 'even']):
                row = [parse_td(td) for td in tr('td')]
                writer = csv.writer(team_data)
                writer.writerow(row)
```

The problem is that some of the url's (`https://www.capfriendly.com/players/'+name`) pages no longer exist. Which means that when I try to scrape them, I get the following error

```
    for tr in table('tr', class_=['column_head', 'odd', 'even']):
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

I could make sure that my list of urls are all valid but I have 10000 urls to go through. That is why I am looking for a way to handle the exception, that way if a page no longer exists, it is skipped and the following url gets scraped.

Also, if there is a more efficient way to store the data, please let me know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Exception handling in python is done with [`try...except` statement](https://docs.python.org/3.6/reference/compound_stmts.html?highlight=try#the-try-statement).

```
    try:
        for tr in table('tr', class_=['column_head', 'odd', 'even']):
            row = [parse_td(td) for td in tr('td')]
            writer = csv.writer(team_data)
            writer.writerow(row)
    except TypeError:
        pass
```

This will ignore the `TypeError` exception raised when `table` is None because the url doesn't exist anymore.
You can also check `table` before the loop, but the `try... except` approach is considered more 'pythonic', since exception handling isn't that much slower than checks in most cases (and for other subjective reasons of course).

Answer (score 0):

I used the following successfully (Python v. 3.9):

```
try:
  <my_code>
except AttributeError:
  <my_code>
```